Добавление и удаление элементов массива через input number в react
Есть input number, с помощью которого я управляю количеством элементов в массиве. Сам массив состоит только из id.
Вот код:
const [Arr, setArr] = useState([{ id: 0 }])

<input type="number" value={Arr.length || ''} min={0} onChange={event => {
   const Item = { id: event.target.value }                
   setArr([...prev, Item])
}} />

Я использую Arr.length в качестве текущего значения. Это прекрасно добавляет значение массива. Но когда нажимается стрелка вниз, значения все равно добавляются. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии стрелки вверх массив добавлял значения, а при нажатии стрелки вниз удалял последнее значение массива. И возможность вводить значение вручную. Например, было 5, а я ввел число 15. И это добавило 15 значений в массив.
Arr.map((Item) => (         
    <Component key={Item.id} id={Item.id}/>             
)

Это рендеринг компонента. Я не могу понять, как вывести количество, указанное во входном числе, с возможностью передачи значения id, тут Item.id.
Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это лучше всего сделать?! Спасибо!
первоначальное решение
const [Count, setCount] = useState('1')

регулятор значения
<input type="number" value={Count || ''} min={0} 
   onChange={event => {
      setCount(event.target.value)
   }} 
/>

рендер компонентов по кол-ву
[...Array(parseInt(Count))].map((_, i) => (
   <Component key={i} id={i} />
))


Вот ваш инпут, там значение 0. Пользователь ввел туда 100 и вы хотите в массиве увидеть 100 элементов? Каких? Зачем?

@SwaD, я думаю, сделаю ограничение до 20 или 30. Все дело в том, что по задумке должен быть input number для рендеринга компонентов. Число 10 = 10 компонентов. И каждый компонент должен удалятся кнопкой "Delete" с клавиатуры. Поэтому, другого решения, кроме, как через массив с id, я не придумал. Изначально, был другой подход к реализации рендера элементов. Сейчас добавлю в вопрос.

@SwaD, я добавил первоначальное решение в конец вопроса. Вот так все работает хорошо. Но в такой реализации я не знаю, как мне удалять выбранный элемент. С получением текущего id={i} из компонента нет проблем. Но как сделать удаление элемента, id которого я извлек? Вот тут я в тупике.

При клике пробегать по массиву и фильтровать его, возвращая элементы без указанного id. Вот пример с ссылкой на песочницу. Как раз то что вы ищите(примерно). По кнопке создаются новые элементы, по кнопке удалить - удаляются.

@SwaD, я так понял, это решение с использованием массива? Я знаю, как удалять элемент массива. Но как удалять текущий элемент в первоначальном решении (без массива), которое я добавил в конец вопроса?! [...Array(parseInt(Count))].map((_, i) => ( ... ). А если речь заходит о массиве, то я не могу понять, как контролировать кол-во записей массива через input number, используя arrow up и arrow down.

Вы в своем решении тоже используете массив. И все работы со списками идут через массивы. Контролировать количество элементов в массиве - только вручную, проверяя текущую длину и входящее значение. Так же методе onChange вам всегда надо проверять новое значение и старое и по разнице понимать, добавлять элемент или удалять. Для удаления есть метод pop()(вам же надо с конца удалять) или slice/splice. Однако суть не поменяется - действие произошло, сравнили значения, определили, что делать с массивом(добавить/удалить), изменили массив, сохранили в состоянии

@SwaD,  ох.. что-то я запутался. Вот так можно будет удалить текущий элемент, если я получил его id={i} --- [...Array(parseInt(Count))].map((_, i) => ( ... ), используя такой стейт const [Count, setCount] = useState('1') ?

Такой стей и рендер - никак. У вас в стейте просто количество, а в рендере вы создаете массив из этого количества и отрисовываете. В текущей реализации "серединку" не убрать. Храните в состоянии сразу массив.

@SwaD, спасибо. Прояснив этот момент, я понял в каком направлении мне идти - массив с id. Не подскажете, что мне указывать в качестве value для input? Arr.length не вариант. Так как я не смогу менять это?! Может переменную, в которую заносить Arr.length ?
